# Quicker Feature Selection Method - R

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection

I am working with a data set that has 4500 observations with about 3800 variables. I'm really struggling to find a time efficient way of performing proper feature selection to get the number of variables down. Things I have done so far:

1. Removed all near zero variance variables (got it down to 3500)
2. Removed all high correlation variables (90%, got it down to 2500)
3. Tried to perform "Both" step wise feature selection and my computer wouldn't even process one round for several days.
4. I am currently trying to run recursive feature selection, but it has been running for over 48 hours now and I'm beginning to become impatient.

The code so far:

```
#Clear Global Environment
rm(list = ls())

#Load Packages Needed For Model and Data
library(readxl)
library(lars)
library(earth)
library(kernlab)
library(party)
library(RWeka)
library(e1071)
library(randomForest)
library(gbm)
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
library(pls)
library(class)
library(FNN)
library(fastDummies)
library(car)
library(lmtest)
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
library(tidyr)

#Bring in Data and clean column Names
load(file = "C:/Rubicon Athletic Investments/Quantitative Modeling/NCAA Football/Models/NCAAF_Model/FinalData.RData")
colnames(Final_Data) <- make.names(colnames(Final_Data))
Data <- Final_Data
Data <- Data[sample(1:nrow(Data)),]

#Substitute Spaces for Underscores
names(Data) <- sub(" ", "_", names(Data))
names(Data) <- sub("-", "_", names(Data))

#Remove Columns Not Needed In Data
dropped_columns <- c("Date","Team.Code","Opponent.Code", "Game_Code", "Year.x","Year.y","Team","Opponent","Points","Win","Total","Overtime")

Data <- Data[,!(names(Data) %in% dropped_columns)]
list_objects <- Data %>% select_if(is.list)
list_objects <- colnames(list_objects)
Data <- unnest(Data, list_objects)
Data <- sapply(Data,as.numeric)
Data <- as.data.frame(Data)
Data[Data == Inf] <- 0
Data[Data == -Inf] <- 0

#Near Zero Predictors
Zero_Vars <- nearZeroVar(Data)
Data <- Data[,-Zero_Vars]

#Create a Non Correlated Data Set
Data <- na.omit(Data)
correlations <- cor(Data)
highcorr <- findCorrelation(correlations, cutoff = 0.90)
Data <- Data[,-highcorr]

#Remove Outliers From the Data
Q <- quantile(Data$MOV, probs = c(0.25, .75), na.rm = FALSE)
IQR <- IQR(Data$MOV)
Upper <- Q[2]+1.5*IQR
Lower <- Q[1]-1.5*IQR
Data <- subset(Data, Data$MOV< Upper & Data$MOV > Lower)

#Create Training and Test Sets
set.seed(1001)
For_Training <- createDataPartition(Data$MOV, p = 0.80)[[1]]
Training <- Data[For_Training,]
Test <- Data[-For_Training,]

# Set Train Control
train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)

#Recursive Feature Elimination Partial Least Squares
predVars <- names(Training)[!names(Training) %in% c("MOV")]
varSeq <- seq(1, ncol(Training), by = 25)
ctrl <- rfeControl(method = "cv",
                   number = 10,
                   verbose = FALSE,
                   functions = caretFuncs) 

Results <- rfe(x = Training[,predVars], y = Training$MOV, sizes = c(2:25, 50, 75, 100,
                                                                    125, 150, 175, 200),
               rfeControl = ctrl)
```

Anything more I could do to get the feature selection time down?

Comment: Your $n$ is fairly close to $p$ in this problem, and so I wouldn't even try something like stepwise selection (ignoring other arguments for its abandonment).  Because your data are close to being wide rather than tall, my advice would be to use something like Relaxo and be done with it.

Comment: Additionally, code snippets are next to worthless without the data.

Comment: Thanks @Demetri Pananos. I was thinking of trying to use an rpart or random forest model then use variable importance but I’m afraid that will take a long time too. I’ve never used Relaxo so I’ll try that.